# Ethernaut lvl1 : Fallback - how to set msg.value when calling contribute()?

Tags: metamask, payments

I'm starting the [ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com) tutorial.

At the level 1, I want to send some eth to a function named contribute.

In the console, I type :

```
await contract.contribute()
```

Then I can't enter the amount in Metamask (loading then error)

[image: metamask]

How can I make my payment type transaction ?

contract code for information :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract Fallback {

  using SafeMath for uint256;
  mapping(address => uint) public contributions;
  address payable public owner;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    contributions[msg.sender] = 1000 * (1 ether);
  }

  modifier onlyOwner {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "caller is not the owner"
        );
        _;
    }

  function contribute() public payable {
    require(msg.value < 0.001 ether);
    contributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    if(contributions[msg.sender] > contributions[owner]) {
      owner = msg.sender;
    }
  }

  function getContribution() public view returns (uint) {
    return contributions[msg.sender];
  }

  function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

  receive() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0 && contributions[msg.sender] > 0);
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just needed to specify amount like this.

```
await contract.contribute({value:toWei("0.0001")})
```

or like this :

```
await contract.contribute({value:1})
```

It worked

I don't know where does the "value" name comes from but one problem at a time...

Comment: value is the function parameter

Comment: Yeah, but in the code contribute takes no parameters :/

Comment: true. it's not a function parameter. It's setting msg.value to the called payable function

Comment: Ok, and where I can find the list of all the available parameters ? what function is called with this parameters ? I suspect https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendtransaction but I'm not sure...

Comment: yeah. eth_call on the page you linked to